# Cancel road hazard tire insurance after purchase

Tags: united-states, car

I got some tires for my vehicle yesterday. I signed the work order and dropped off the vehicle; my spouse picked up the vehicle and paid the bill. On the bill was an $80 charge for road hazard insurance. Even if such insurance was a good deal (it's not), we plan on selling the vehicle in a year or so, so we won't be able to take advantage of most of the lifetime of the policy. We never received any documentation about the insurance, so I don't even know what the lifetime is.

My spouse called and was given a litany of excuses:

- "You didn't pay for this, we (the shop) paid for it, because you got
  a discount on the tires." Those two aspects of the transaction are
  unrelated.
- " talked to your husband about this." No he
  did not, because I would have declined.
- " already put it in the system." Doesn't answer whether we cancel or not.
- " day off is today. He'll be back Thursday." Washington state has a 3-day "cooling off period" though I'm not sure that the period applies to this kind of transaction.

Should I keep trying to get them to cancel it? Or should I just chalk it up to lessons learned, and make a helpful note to potential customers on Yelp etc?

Comment: How did you pay?  If on a credit card I'd contact the bank.

Comment: Yes with a credit card. But can you dispute part of a charge like this when 90% of it was legit (we did receive tires) and the other 10%, you signed for, even if they never asked you about it explicitly?

Comment: I think it depends on the issuing bank, it's worth a call though.

Comment: @stannius definitely dispute. I'd suggest also calling the State oversight agency, there must be one for the auto shops...

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

- Send an email stating explicitly that you did not ask for this insurance and telling them to refund it. Do this now so it is within any cooling off period you think there might be.
- You might also consider following this up with a written letter, saying the same thing, and hand-deliver it to someone at the shop. Make a note of the name of the person you deliver it to and the time. Keep a copy.
- Contact your credit card company to dispute the part of the bill for the insurance, if that is possible.
- Threaten them with small claims court.